# Mocking functional sequences in Scala

Tags: unit-testing, scala, functional-programming

One long standing problem I have when writing unit tests in Scala is how to deal with mocking collaborators that use functional composition.

Generally in programming long call chains are considered code smells ("train wreck code") but this seems to be specific to object oriented structures; in functional languages, long call chains naturally appear. For example:

```
obj.step1 andThen obj.step2 andThen obj.step3
```

where `stepX` are the units of reuse and composition. If, however, `obj` appears as a collaborator in another object, this becomes very cumbersome to mock out. With Mockito, this would become something like:

```
when(obj.step1).thenReturn((x) => x)
when(obj.step2).thenReturn((x) => x)
when(obj.step3).thenReturn((x) => x)
```

so that the call chain does not break. This is also a very weak test, since the test subject might or might not have called step3 so I will have to combine the call chain stubbing with additional verifications.

I was wondering if there's a more idiomatic way in Scala to deal with such objects when they become dependencies? The only options I considered so far are:

- use deep mocks (e.g. using Mockito), which is generally considered a smell
- use a hand written mock, which records every composition step

Both seem not ideal to me.